# Getting different String from snapshot.getKey(); and mAuth.getUid(); Without .push();

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

String I am getting from snapshot.getKey(); is different from any other String, although I am not doing push() if i virtually compare the values of my mAuth.getUid(); string and snapshot.getKey(); they both are same, but programmatically it is not showing.
I tried concatinating my snapshot.getKey(); string in textView.setText(snapshot.getKey();); also but nothing is shown in the screen.

Please note I am not posting my whole Fragment code.

In the code below the if statement is not getting true value.

```
FirebaseUser mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference userref = databaseReference.child("Votes").child("Chat");    

final HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<>();

    likeButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.heartImage);

    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hash.put("chatVoteLike", "Yes, I would like it");
            userref.child(mAuth.getUid()).setValue(hash);
            likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);
        }
    });


    userref.orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

               String uID = snapshot.getKey();
                Log.i("uId from", "firebase ---" + uID);

              if (uID == mAuth.getUid()){
                  likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);
              }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: my database structure image below]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: So you basically say that `mAuth.getUid()` and `snapshot.getKey()` return different result, right?

Comment: Yes, virtually the results are same but Programmatically  they are different, although both are String .

Comment: @AlexMamo help me please

Comment: So `uID == mAuth.getUid()` is always false, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, it is always false. Even i checked values of both in logcat, it was same, but the condition is false.

Comment: Where in code are you checking that condition and you say that in the logcat are the same?

Comment: @AlexMamo look from bottom 12th line if (uID == mAuth.getUid()){
                  likeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);
              }

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839

Comment: Try using `uID.equals(mAuth.getUid())` instead of `uID == mAuth.getUid()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is Solved using using `uID.equals(mAuth.getUid())` instead of `uID == mAuth.getUid()`